# Apply filter on container div and not child divs

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
    <div class="artist_photo">
        <div class="artist_name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this CSS

```
    .artist_photo {
        background-image: url('path/to/artist/photo');
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    }

    .artist_name {
        background-color: rgba(228,88,0,0.9);
    }
```

The photo from the `.artist_photo` div appears black and white as desired but so does the `.artist_name` div which is not desired. How can I remove the filter from the child div?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can do this. But you can do something like wrapping the two divs with another div. So `.artist_photo` won't contain `.artist_name`, and give `.artist_photo` an absolute position etc. so it will be all over the background of their ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done, as you require; the `filter` property will, much like `opacity`, be applied to the element and all its contents. One way around this is to use pseudo-elements (such as `::before` or `::after`) to contain the image you wish to show in grayscale:

```css
.artist_photo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
.artist_photo::after {
  content: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/2');
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
.artist_name {
  background-color: rgba(228, 88, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="artist_photo">
  <div class="artist_name">Some text</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t69a9y1d/).

Alternatively you could use another element to wrap the `.artist_name` and `.artist_photo` as siblings, applying the filter to the `.artist_photo`:

```css
.artist_wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
.artist_photo {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/2');
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.artist_name {
  background-color: rgba(228, 88, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="artist_wrapper">
  <div class="artist_name">Some text</div>
  <div class="artist_photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t69a9y1d/1/).

Comment: This looks great, but I actually load the `background-image` from the `style` tag in html because I load the image with javascript. Anyway around that? Thank you

Comment: Can you update your question with the JavaScript you're using? Ideally posting an "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)" code snippet *in your question*, that can include/be a Stack Snippet or include a link to a demo site (such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) *as well as* including said minimal code in your question.

Comment: The second solution works for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)